# Resolve the console warning "JQMIGRATE: jQuery.event.props.concat() is deprecated and removed" with KendoUI(2018.2.515)

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, jquery-migrate

While upgrading jQuery fro 1.9.1 to 3.1.1 usign jquery migrate plugin 3.0.0 ,
I am getting an console warning from migrate plugin like below. How to resolve this ? Upgrading kendo acrosss a big project could be very painful.
[image]

Comment: Kendo UI 2015.3.1111 is not compatible with jQuery 3.1.1 cf https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/prerequisites. You should migrate to at least Kendo UI 2016.3.1118

Comment: Yeah true from the prerequisites.Thanks.

Comment: I am using kendo 2018.2.515 with jquery 3.1.1 and migrate plugin along with it and i see these errors. How can we go about fixing these issues that originate from a library?

Answer (score 1):

Kendo UI 2018.2.516 is not compatible with jQuery 3.1.1, but you have two options to solve this.

1) Downgrade Kendo to Kendo UI 2018.1.117, which is compatible with jQuery 3.1.1

2) Upgrade jQuery to 3.3.1, which is compatible with Kendo UI 2018.1.117

From the Docs:

> Kendo UI 2018.2.516 (R2 2018)     1.12.4  Also compatible with 1.10.x,
>   2.2.x and 3.3.1
>   Kendo UI 2018.1.117 (R1 2018)     1.12.4  Also compatible with 1.10.x, 2.2.x and 3.1.1

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/prerequisites#supported-jquery-versions